# Return 2 variables in c#

Tags: c#

I am to change two variables in one method but how am I supposed to return both? Without an array. I guess `Tuple<>` should help but I don't know how to take a variable. This code is supposed to take special substrings.

```
public static List<string> SomethingInsideTheOther(List<int> listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1, List<int> listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2, List<string> listOfBoxes, string text)
{
    int beggining = Math.Min(listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[0], listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[0]);
    if (beggining != 0)
    {
        listOfBoxes.Add(text.Substring(0, beggining));
    }
    int i = 0;
    int g = 0;
    for ( ; i < listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1.Count - 1;)
    {                
        for ( ; g < listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2.Count - 1;)
        {
            if (listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[i] < listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[g])
            {                        
                 listOfBoxes.Add(text.Substring(listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[i], listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[i + 1] - listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[i] + 1));
                 WhenILssG(i, g, listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1, listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2); 
                 i =                     
            }
            else
            {
                listOfBoxes.Add(text.Substring(listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[g], listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[g + 1] - listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[g] + 1));                        
                WhenIGtrG(i, g, listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1, listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2);
            }
            break;
        }                
        goto end;
    }
    end:
    return listOfBoxes;
 }

public static Tuple<int, int> WhenILssG(int i, int g, List<int> listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1, List<int> listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2)
{
    i += 1;
    while (listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[i] > listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[g] && g < listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2.Count - 1)
    {
        g += 1;
    }
    i += 1;
    return new Tuple<int, int>(i, g);
 }


public static Tuple<int, int> WhenIGtrG(int i, int g, List<int> listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1, List<int> listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2)
{                                   
    g += 1;
    while (listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1[i] < listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks2[g] && i < listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1.Count - 1)
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    g += 1;
    return new Tuple<int, int>(i, g);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean you "don't know how to take a variable"?  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: oh, sorry, I meant variables. Both.

Comment: Wow, an actual `goto` statement in the wild...

Comment: @Paul_was_taken: But it's still not clear what the problem is.  The methods *appear* to be successfully returning `Tuple<>` objects.  If something isn't working, please clarify.

Comment: after `Tuple<int, int> WhenILssG`  or `Tuple<int, int> WhenIGtrG` niether i nor g are changed.

Comment: just a side note. a better style of programming i suggest you use more suitable names for variables. you dont have to write sentence as a name. thats not common and not readable. for example instead of `listOfPositionsOfQuotationMarks1` use `quotMarksList_1` or something like that. add comment behind variable name if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an object-oriented language, so define an object that holds the return values.

The `Tuple` approach is also okay (although I'd argue it's less clear, and therefore less preferable), but the problem is that you're using the wrong method to create it. You can use the static method `Tuple.Create` to create a new `Tuple`.

Or you can explicitly state the type of the `Tuple` in the constructor: `var newTuple = new Tuple<int, int>(value1, value2)`